# Variogram model - SAGA on QGIS Processing

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, saga, kriging, variogram

QGIS 2.14 (Win) comes with SAGA 2.12, which Ordinary Kriging supports 6 variogram model options.

[image: SAGA 2.12]

However, if I run SAGA Ordinary Kriging from QGIS Processing Toolbox, there is no drop down menu. Only an entry box in which an equation *a + bx* is shown.

[image: QGIS Processing SAGA Ordinary Kriging]

QGIS 2.14 user guide [Kriging](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/kriging.html) explains these options, so I can expect them coming. (future...not now).

Do you know any documentation about how to set variogram models in SAGA on QGIS Processing Toolbox? (Ideally, is there any working example?)

At the moment I am playing with Meuse river dataset, so a reference to Spherical model is desirable. (It is not important for now, though.)

[image]

So far I tried to manually put equation in the box (like above), which gave me a *Kriging-like* map. But I have zero confidence in what I am doing.

---

I installed SAGA 3.0 on QGIS 2.18 Processing, which was the same.

Comment: In order to perform a good Kriging Model you will have to make a variogram that matches your dataset (or which comes closest to it). Without actually visualizing your model you will have a hard time picking the right model from a drop-down menu. I therefor prefer using Arcgis or even software like Surfer to first make the variogram and than apply the used setting/parameters to make your Kriging.

Comment: @KonanPruiksma Ugh, your comment reminded me I have forgotten to mention that the parameters came from {gstat} package in R. Sorry, and thanks pointing out that. I cannot agree with you more about importance of getting right model. My question, however, was not about those parameters, but how I can put them in the User Interface in the Processing Toolbox. Just "a+b*x" does not give me much clue.

Comment: Aah sorry I did not understand your question. After looking at the Kriging guide from QGIS you provided the parameters you put for the Variogram Model within the SAGA toolbox should not be an equation but a number corresponding to the model you wish to apply. In the guide it says this: 0 — [0] Spherical Model
1 — [1] Exponential Model
2 — [2] Gaussian Model
3 — [3] Linear Regression
4 — [4] Exponential Regression
5 — [5] Power Function Regression

Comment: @KonanPruiksma Thanks checking out the QGIS 2.14 documentation. If I put such numbers, say [0] in the box, what I get is a grid file with cells of all "nan". I can be totally wrong, but I think I need to somehow provide variogram model and parameters altogether in an equation style. I feel (hopefully) it will be equipped with drop-down menus sometime in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found this template in SAGA GUI (2.0.1), in the interactive mode of Ordinary Kriging (global).

[image: equation template]

So a Spherical model can be like: [image: new semivariogram model]

And I got this;
[image: result]

[Note] If anybody kindly volunteer to test this workflow, this sample point data and parameters are reproduced by R commands:

```
library(sp)
data(meuse, package= "sp")
coordinates(meuse)= ~x + y
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")

library(rgdal)
writeOGR(meuse, ".", "meuse_points", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")

library(gstat)
vgm1 <- variogram(log(zinc)~1, meuse)
fit.variogram(vgm1, vgm("Sph"))       # Nugget= 0.214, Range= 514.4
plot(vgm1)                            # Sill ~ 0.85 by visual
```

Comment: I am new to understanding krigging, Can you please tell me how to find this parameters like above 0.214 , is this values changes from set points (region to region)

Comment: Hi @sudhanshud In R {gstat} package, `fit.variogram()` function gives us Nugget, and Range for designated variogram model. I needed to plot it to find Sill (Psill). For some reason it returned different values now, so please do not trust the above values (0.214, 514.4).It may be my stupid mistake.