# What should be different variogram model in kriging

Tags: qgis-processing, kriging, variogram

In ordinary kriging algorithm in QGIS (Saga algorithms provided in QGIS) there is field for Variogram model which by default is given as 'a + b * x' what does it signify and what are other options to provide and their significance?

PS: I need to know about various kriging variogram models and how to provide their equations in Kriging algorithm as in below Image

PFB Image:
[image]

Comment: What does the help say it does?

Comment: You are facing the same issue I had... when I opened this module in SAGA itself (ie SAGA GUI), it became obvious. FYI, please see this [Variogram model - SAGA on QGIS Processing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224640/variogram-model-saga-on-qgis-processing).

Comment: @Kazuhito  - As per [Krigging Doc](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/kriging.html) specific options are given here, do I need to specify those option in [ ] as giving only numbers like 0 or 1 giving me same output 
Also where can I know about the equation for those models?

Comment: Yes it is the document I had referred to, and confused me as well (you can find it in my post). So the answer to the first part is NO, those numbers 0 or 1 does not work. As to "how to know about the equation", I found it in SAGA, but you can start with the captured image I had posted in my answer. HTH.