# QGIS 3.6 ordinary kriging produce one constant output

Tags: kriging

When I run kriging a+bx or any other model, I always get just one constant output. I have selected collect attribute. 
Prediction and quality layer has just one value.

[image]

see output here:

[image]

Comment: maximum distance -1. What is that doing?

Comment: Just checking you have built statistics on the output or ran info to check that is all the values in the raster

Comment: -1 is default value. i tried 10 and 100 as well.

Comment: I think its lacking documentation as the moment.

Comment: Min and Max in 'quality measure' and 'prediction' layer are same.

Comment: Hi QGIS_krig and welcome to GIS SE. How have you set `Variogram model` in the dialog? You might be in a similar situation as I was before; [Variogram model - SAGA on QGIS Processing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224640/variogram-model-saga-on-qgis-processing)

Comment: i tried default a+b*x and then i tried a+b*x+c*x^2+d*x^3. i see that it calculates some value for a,b,c,d parameters.